# How to change "Languages" in App Store description?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect

I've released app on App Store, with Primary Language - Russian.
But after release, App Store shows only one available language - English.

Please advice where should I change language settings to correctly include it in App Store release?

[image: App Store Connect screenshot]

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: same happened to me, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Open your xcodeproj-file in Finder (right-click -> Show Package Contents), than edit file project.pbxproj.
Find "developmentRegion"-parameter in file and replace value. For example, write "ru" instead "en".
After that add your new language to "knownRegions"-parameter.
If your app support only one language, set "knownRegions"-parameter as your language and "Base". Thats all.